# Is there any difference in the emotional intensity by saying "I would like to", and "I would love to"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, idioms

I heard that there is a delicate difference between "I would like to" and " I would love to."

Could you please tell me the difference in meaning between "I would like to" and " I would love to"?

Comment: For any *given* speaker it's possible they might think ***love*** is more "emphatic" than ***like***, but as a general principle you can't assume anything like that. It's like the fact that some people "casually" exclaim *Oh my God!* in relatively unsurprising contexts, whereas others are so unflappable they probably wouldn't say that even if God himself appeared before them in the form of a (talking) burning bush.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I would expect that, whether a person uses "love to" casually or otherwise, they would use it to provide greater emphasis than "like to." The question is flagged as "primarily opinion-based", but I'm voting to leave it open because I think there might be a non-opinion-based answer in it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers agreed.  And when one person says "I would love to", it's not necessarily more emphatic than a different person who says "I would like to."  Age, region, the audience, would all affect whether a given person would say 'like' or 'love', and what they meant by it.

Comment: @John Feltz: Yeah. You might as well ask who's more contrite if three different people say *I'm very sorry, I'm really sorry, I'm truly sorry.* Or indeed, *I'm totally sorry*, which might mark someone out as a bit sloppy with language, but that doesn't mean they can't experience deep remorse.

Answer (score 3):

People use **love to** and **like to** for all sort of things. **love to** is  more intense than **like to**, but the degree of intensity is relative to the situation at hand. The phrases can have very little or quite a lot of emotion behind them.

> I'd love to know where my car keys went.
>
> I'd like to know where my car keys went.
>
> I'd love to punch that jerk in the nose.
>
> I'd like to punch that jerk in the nose.
>
> I'd love to be in a position to help my brother out financially.
>
> I'd like to be in a position to help my brother out financially.

Answer (score 2):

*I would (I'd) love to* is the basic way to accept an invitation to do something:

A: Would you like to join me for dinner?

B: I'd love to.

As for the degree of empathy in *I would love to go with you* and *I would like to go with you*, FumbleFingers' comment covers the ground ultimately.

Comment: There is a difference between attempting to distinguish *I would like to join you* and *I would love to join you* (futile, imho), and your exact example. To my ear, unqualified *I'd like to* would be a relatively unlikely response from B (unless immediately negated / tempered, as in *I'd like to, **but** I'm washing my hair tonight*).